# Where to put external script and css includes in a codeigniter project

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, include

Ok so of course I'm aware that your assets folder will hold your main css and js files but my question is for external script includes like jquery ui or something.  For example I'm using datepicker on a page and it will only work with these two includes:

```html
    <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">

    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

currently they are just sitting on the top of my view file that has the datepicker.  However this does not seem right.  It seems it should be loaded in someway cleaner then this.  Is there a specific folder that these kinds of includes are kept in codeigniter?  And if so is there a special function to call them like `urihelper()` or something?

Thanks

Comment: please define more detailed: how is your page structured, which views are loaded from the controller, how many controllers load different views, etc

Comment: Ok so this page is a fairly simple operation.  It's a form page and it's called from the contorller called webinars.php.  The index function just returns $this->template('webinar/index')  which is the page that currently holds these includes

Comment: I believe the mains css and js file are called in the constructor of the main controller that is extended in every other controller.  I guess I could do the same for these?  but I do not want them included in every view on the site.

Comment: why not? if you load it from a cdn (like code.jquery.com), they are cached anyway. make sure the ui is called after the main jquery

Comment: Ok so that's what most people would do in this case.  Just tag them to the main controller that every view touches?  I guess yea why not.

Comment: actually just talked to my coworker and he says there's a function you can add to the controller when you're calling your view that will include the scripts.  Thanks though!

Comment: that's a bit of a overhead, IMO. I just put the css in a header view, where e.g. the menu's are loaded and the scripts in a footer view. In between place all the variable content views you need

Comment: You can separate out commonly used CSS and JS files and maintain view files to each of them like header and footer. Then you can include them while loading the view in the order you want to show them.